# Convergence of the expectation of a non-continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, probability-theory

Suppose that $F_{n}$ converges to $F$ weakly, where $F$ is a continuous distribution function.

Also, suppose that $g$ is a bounded, continuous function and 
$\{x_{n}\}$ is a real-valued sequence of real numbers such that 
$x_{n} \longrightarrow x$.

I want to show that 
$$
\lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty}\int 1[t \geq x_{n}] g(t) dF_{n}(t)
= \lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty}\int_{x_{n}}^{\infty} g(t) dF_{n}(t)
= \int_{x}^{\infty} g(t)dF(t)
$$
I believe the above is true when $F$ is continuous (not necessarily otherwise).
Is there a quick proof of this fact, or is there a citation for this result?

Comment: As you noted, it's not true when $dF$ has point masses. There are counterexamples.

Comment: The claim comes down to the following: $dF_n([x_n, x]) \rightarrow dF([x_n, x])$ under the assumption that $dF$ has a continuous CDF.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|g(u)| \le M. $Fix $\epsilon>0$. Now choose $\delta>0$ such that 
$$
\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}F(u)du < \epsilon
$$
We can do as above via continuity of $F$. Since $F_n \to F$ and $x_n \to x$,
There exists $N=N(\epsilon)>0$ such that for all $n>N$
$$
|\int_{x_n}^{\infty}g(u)F_n(u)du - \int_{x+\delta}^{\infty}g(u)F_n(u)du|<M\int_{x+\delta}^{x-\delta}F_n(u)du < 2\epsilon$$
and,
$$
|\int_{x+\delta}^{\infty}g(u)F_n(u)du - \int_{x+\delta}^{\infty}g(u)F(u)du|<\epsilon
$$
Combining above three, we get for $n >N,$

$$
|\int_{x_n}^{\infty}g(u)F_n(u)du-\int_{x}^{\infty}g(u)F(u)du|<4\epsilon
$$

and done.